# Why my Authorize Action Method is Anonymous in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

***AccountController***

This is my Account Controller and i have a User Model from where i just gonna fetch Email and Password.

```cs
public ActionResult Login(User model, string ReturnUrl)
{
    using(DbAccess db=new DbAccess())
    {
       var user=db.users.Where(m => m.email == model.email && m.password == model.password).FirstOrDefault();
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.username,user.RemmemberMe);
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
       {
           return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
       }
       else
       {
           return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
       }     
    }
}
```

***HomeController***

Here you can see this is Home Controller where i use allow anonymous attribute on whole controller but About Action Method has Authorize attribute...

```cs
[AllowAnonymous]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

***WebConfig***

This this my web.config file...

```cs
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Now the problem is when i'm login then i can access all the Action Methods either they are Anonymous or Authorize ,what i expected but when i logout and i redirected to Login page than when again i try to access Authorize Action Method than yeah it redirect me to that Method i mean it accessed by unauthorized user.

Further I have cleared browser full history with cookies etc but its not working for me

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Rick Anderson at [MSDN Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/), please read it for more details.

> In MVC, by default all controllers + actions are accessible to all
>   users, both authenticated and guest. To secure controllers or actions,
>   the Authorize attribute has been provided.

You need to do the opposite. Secure all the application controllers as well as action method and `AllowAnonymos` on those controller actions which can be accessed by anyone logged in user or anonymous user.

Your modified code should look like this.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }
}
```